# How to apply formula on all values of one column in sql server in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I am making payroll management system in which double pay salary is equal to some proportion of employee's fix pay.That proportion is given by some percentage i.e. 12% of fix pay and this percentage tends to change time by time. And when the percentage is changed then double pay value according to that percentage must also be changed in employee table. 
here is my code:

```
  string query;
                query = "select count(*) from ConditionalEarnings where [Double Duty]!=0";
            SqlCommand value = new SqlCommand(query,DataFind);
            value.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int no = Convert.ToInt32(value.ExecuteScalar());
            textBox7.Text = no.ToString();
            for (int o = 0; o< no; o++)
            {
                string query1;
                query1 = "select EmpId from ConditionalEarnings where [Double Duty]!=0";
                SqlCommand value1 = new SqlCommand(query1, DataFind);
                value1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(value1.ExecuteScalar());
                textBox8.Text = id.ToString();
                string query2;
                query2 = "Select EmpRunningBasic from EmployeeRunningBasic where EmpId=@id";
                SqlCommand r = new SqlCommand(query2,DataFind);
                r.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;
                r.ExecuteNonQuery();
                int rb = Convert.ToInt32(r.ExecuteScalar());
                int doublechange = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
             int   apply = (rb * doublechange)/100;

             SqlCommand f = new SqlCommand("Update  ConditionalEarnings set [Double Duty]='" + apply + "' where EmpId=@id", DataFind);
             f.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;
             f.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
```

And my form is as follow:
[Its my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNqff.jpg)

This is my code to perform task.
When I enter percentage and execute program to update all values in that specific column of double pay, only 1st row of table is changed and all other row's cell for double duty remain unchanged. Means my program works in a loop and calculate and replace value of my first row's column again and again without going to the next row. How to apply change on all rows selected on base of same criteria?

[its my table showing employee id column and double duty column highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZdnA.jpg)

The value of double duty column is not changing for all employee ids but for only first id in table.

Comment: Seems like an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Please show relevant tables DDL, some sample data as DML, and desired output.

Comment: depending on value of textbox , calculations must be made and values in table must be updated  after calculations , thats what I need!!!!!!

Comment: Deam Maaz. Please read [ask] and try to understand that people here answer questions on their own spare time. No one here is getting paid to answer questions, מo one owes anybody anything.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the Employees (with their Running Basics) that you want to Iterate, then apply your calculation on every one then update your database

have a look at the below code , it may help you **(modify the code to match your needs)**

```
        int no = 0;
        string query = "select count(*) from ConditionalEarnings where [Double Duty]!=0";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            no = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }

        string selectQuery = "select a.EmpId,b.EmpRunningBasic from ConditionalEarnings a left join EmployeeRunningBasic b on a.EmpId=b.EmpId  where a.[Double Duty]!=0";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, DataFind);
        DataTable dtEmp;
        adapter.Fill(dtEmp);

        textBox7.Text = no.ToString();

        string updateQuery = "";
        foreach (DataRow row in dtEmp)
        {
            string empId = row["EmpId"].ToString();
            textBox8.Text = empId;
            int rb = Convert.ToInt32(row["EmpRunningBasic"]);
            int doublechange = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            int apply = (rb * doublechange) / 100;

            updateQuery += string.Format("Update  ConditionalEarnings set [Double Duty]='{1}' where EmpId='{0}';", empId, apply);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(updateQuery))
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, conn);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```